# Excel VBA - cell value returns "False" instead of the value

Tags: excel, function, vba

I'm trying to return the value of a cell in an Excel spreadsheet, but it just shows "False" instead of the value of the cell.

Here's the function:

```
Function GenSelectStatement() As String    

Dim retstring As String    
Dim i As Integer    

retstring = Cells(1, 2).Select
MsgBox "restring: " & Cells(2, 2).Select      
GenSelectStatement = retstring    

End Function
```

The cell in question has an alpha value like "xxx".

Both the msgbox display and the cell where the function is coded show "FALSE".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code makes no sense, I'm afraid. You set the value of the `retstring` **variable** to `Cells(1,2).Select`, `MsgBox` using a **constant** (not the variable)  `"retstring:"`) + a different Cell.Select `(2, 2)` instead of the original `(1, 2)`, and then return the first selected cell. Please post an example (in text) of the content of the spreadsheet columns and an example of what you're  trying to obtain from that spreadsheet as a result of your function, so we can try and help you. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Select is to select the cell.

If you want the value of the cell, try :

```
Worksheets("Data").Range("$P$1").Value
```

Take a look on that link:
http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=11530

Regards,
Jim.

Comment: Thanks - I was starting to think "what about value" and there was your answer. Much appreciated.